# Unknown argument -cp : Spurious errors with Ant

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to set up nightlybuilds using Apache-ant. I have apache-ant-1.8.2, with Java 1.6, on openSUSE 11.4 64 bit.

I have setup a separate VM. It keeps throwing up the following error:

```
nightlybuilds@linux-99n0:~> ant
Unknown argument: -cp
ant [options] [target [target2 [target3] ...]]

nightlybuilds@linux-99n0:~/builds> ant -v
Unknown argument: -cp
ant [options] [target [target2 [target3] ...]]
```

I removed `/etc/ant.conf`. I did `zypper install ant` and downloaded loads of jar files. System says `/usr/bin/ant` when I do `which ant`. And running it with the `--noconfig` option also does not help.

What can the problem be?

Comment: Do you have any funny aliases, or modified java scripts/helpers?

Comment: Does `ant -version` work? Maybe there is a problem with your build.xml.

Comment: Even ant -version throws up the same thing.  No funny aliases :( Its a new VM.  No changes made to it :(

Answer (score 1):

The -cp should be there. You may check alises as Mat has suggested:

`alias ant`

I will suggest checking your ANT_HOME as proposed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ant/+bug/207105

You can also check what launcher is trying to execute by:

```
ant --execdebug
```