# Unknown argument: -cp ANT1.9.1

Tags: java, windows, ant

My OS is Win7,I download ant-1.9.1 ant unzip to d:\
after I set ANT_HOME ,run in CMD I GOT below error:

```
C:\Users\hp>ant
Unknown argument: -cp
ant [options] [target [target2 [target3] ...
Options:
-help, -h              print this message
```

Here is something about my OS settings:

```
C:\Users\hp>javac -version
 javac 1.7.0_15
C:\Users\hp>java -version
 java version "1.7.0_15"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)
 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And:

```
C:\Users\hp>path
PATH=D:\apache-ant-1.9.1\bin;D:\Python27;E:\Develop\Android\android-sdk-windows\
platform-tools\;E:\Develop\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\;C:\Program Files (
x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files
(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Window
s Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Common Files\NetSarang;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows
\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Inte
l\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files
(x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\
Shared;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;D:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\Program Files\Tortois
eHg\;

C:\Users\hp>echo %classpath%
.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\lib\dt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
 \jdk1.7.0_15\lib\tools.jar;

 C:\Users\hp>echo %ANT_HOME%
 D:\apache-ant-1.6.1
```

I have read [Unknown argument -cp : Spurious errors with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495771/unknown-argument-cp-spurious-errors-with-ant)  and  http://marc.info/?l=ant-user&m=113074222502480
while i thought these posts has nothing to do with my problem!
Any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had such an issue also some time ago
the solution that did the job for me was to edit the **ant.bat** file (there where some arguments passed to the jre the just didn't work on my configuration)

KR
Florian